# Do these table setups make sense? Trying to perform a specific SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Employee table

```
emp_no  emp_fname emp_lname job_title   job_begin
    18316   John    Barrimore   Driver  6/1/2015
    28559   Sybill  Moser       ---         8/1/2015
    28559   Sybill  Moser       Engineer    2/1/2016
    33355   Peter   Fisher      ---          ---
    2581    Elke    Hansel      Analyst 10/15/2015
    9031    Elsa    Bertoni     Manager 4/15/2015
    9031    Elsa    Bertoni     Engineer    11/15/2014
    29346   James   James       Engineer    1/4/2015
    29346   James   James       ---         12/15/2014
    30606   Kathie  Willson     Analyst 9/25/2015
    30606   Kathie  Willson     Programmer  ---
    10102   Ann Jones           Analyst 10/1/2014
    10102   Ann Jones           Manager 1/1/2012
    25348   Jerry   Smith       Engineer    2/15/2015
    --- --- --- --- ---
    31189   Julia   White   --- ---
    35500   Ben Wells   --- ---
    --- --- --- --- ---
    5500    Paul    Fisher        QA    ---
    5500    Paul    Fisher        Programmer 11/9/2016
    5500    Paul    Fisher        QA     3/22/2016
    5500    Paul    Fisher        Manager    1/18/2013
    34427   Matthew Arrow   --- ---
    --- --- --- --- ---
```

Department table

```
emp_no  dept_no dept_name   dept_location
18316   d1      R&D         Dallas, TX
28559   d1      R&D         Dallas, TX
28559   d1      R&D         Dallas, TX
33355   d1      R&D         Dallas, TX
2581    d2      Accounting  Tampa, FL
9031    d2      Accounting  Tampa, FL
9031    d2      Accounting  Tampa, FL
29346   d2      Accounting  Tampa, FL
29346   d2      Accounting  Tampa, FL
30606   d2      Accounting  Tampa, FL
30606   d2      Accounting  Tampa, FL
10102   d3      Marketing   Miami, FL
10102   d3      Marketing   Miami, FL
25348   d3      Marketing   Miami, FL
--- ---         Shipping    Atlanta, GA
31189   d5      Sales       Tampa, FL
35500   d5      Sales       Tampa, FL
--- ---     Customer Service St. Louis, MO
5500    --- --- ---
5500    --- --- ---
5500    --- --- ---
5500    --- --- ---
34427   --- --- ---
--- --- --- ---
```

Project table

```
emp_no  proj_no proj_name proj_budget
18316   p2  Gemini        $95,000.00
28559   p1  Anchor        $120,000.00
28559   p2  Gemini        $95,000.00
33355   --- --- ---
2581    p3  Jet           $186,500.00
9031    p1  Anchor        $120,000.00
9031    p3  Jet           $186,500.00
29346   p1  Anchor        $120,000.00
29346   p2  Gemini        $95,000.00
30606   p11 Sea Star    ---
30606   p20 Hunter-II   ---
10102   p1  Anchor       $120,000.00
10102   p3  Jet          $186,500.00
25348   p2  Gemini       $95,000.00
--- --- --- ---
31189   --- --- ---
35500   --- --- ---
--- --- --- ---
5500    p11 Sea Star    ---
5500    p14 Blue Sky    $300,000.00
5500    p2  Gemini      $95,000.00
5500    p20 Hunter-II   ---
34427   --- --- ---
--- ---     Winner          $300,000.00
```

I am trying to find the project that has the most employees from the same department, but I am not sure if I can given how I set up the table data. I included the emp_no column in each table so I could do joins easier but I am still unsure how to go about it. The headers were given to me, and I thought this was the best way to set up the data; however, I am confused on how to go about this.

Comment: If I'm interpreting this correctly, all you need to do is join your `Project` table to your `Department` table on `emp_no`. Then do a group by on `proj_no`, `dept_name`, and `count(*)`

Comment: Why would `Department` table contains information about an employee???  Why would `Project` table contains information about an employee???  This is a very bad table design.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming an employee only belongs to one department, then no, that table setup is not a good schema design. The `Department` table should not include the `emp_no`. It should only have one row for each department entity, and the `Employee` table should also include a `dept_no` field.

If the assumption is wrong, and an employee might be listed with more than one department, *still remove `emp_no` from the `Department` table and reduce down to one row per department.* But now, instead of adding `dept_no` to the `Employee` table, you create an additional `EmployeeDeptartments` table with both `emp_no` and `dept_no` fields for assigning employees to departments. This is also useful if you want to track employee locations over time, where it's value to know that an employee worked for a specific department at some time in the past. You can do this by adding datetime fields to the table.

The same thing applies to the `Project` table. This table should only have one row for each project, and you need a separate `EmployeeProjects` table to see what people are working on.

*This is important!* For example, I see project `p1` has several rows, each with a budget of $120,000,000. You don't want the possibility that one row in the table for that project somehow ends up with a different budget number than other rows with the same project.

Later on, you can get a listing that looks like the current `Project` or `Department` tables by writing a query with `JOIN` statement.

---

> "I am trying to find the project that has the most employees from the same department."

Going with the option where an employee can only belong to a single department, that would look like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 p.proj_no, p.proj_name, e.dept_no, COUNT(e.emp_no) As NumEmployeesByDept
FROM Project p
INNER JOIN EmployeeProjects ep on ep.proj_no = p.proj_no
INNER JOIN Employee e on e.emp_no = ep.emp_no
GROUP BY p.proj_no, p.proj_name, e.dept_no
ORDER BY COUNT(e.emp_no) DESC
```

You could also use a windowing function rather than aggregation, to handle a situation where there might be ties.

Comment: Take note of the extra relationship tables suggested here, @Chris. I assumed there was a dept to project relationship, but that may not be correct now that I'm thinking about it, and Joel's suggestions would account for that.

Comment: After reviewing my data, no employee belongs to multiple departments, so I would not need an EmployeeDepartments table. However, there are multiple departments working on the same project(s), so I would need that EmployeeProjects table. My question is, what columns would I include in EmployeeProjects? I assume I keep Project columns dept_no, proj_no, proj_name, and proj_budget. Would EmployeeProjects have emp_no, proj_no, and dept_no?

Comment: You need at  least `emp_no` and `proj_no`. You probably don't need `dept_no`, but you could make a case for including the `dept_no` column if an employee might move to a different department in the future, and when that happens you still want to know what department they were with when first assigned to the project... but I'd lean against this.

Answer (score 1):

No, your data model doesn't make sense.

Tables are entities. Columns are attributes. Rows are values.

Employee number is not an attribute of either `Department` or `Project`, and it doesn't belong in either of those tables. It's presence there is forcing you to violate first normal form by endlessly repeating all of the department and project values for every employee number. If an employee moves between departments, you have to modify the data in three tables.

The `Employee` table should include a `dept_no` attribute, and the value should be the department to which that employee is currently assigned. Remove `emp_no` from `Department` and normalize that table. There should only be as many rows in `Department` as there are departments.

The `Project` table should include a `dept_no` attribute; the department that owns the project. It should not include `emp_no`. Once corrected, that data should be normalized. There should only be as many rows in `Project` as there are projects.

Once you have normalized tables, your query will start with the `Project` table, which you'll join to `Department` via `dept_no`, then join again to `Employee`, again via `dept_no`. Once the joins are set up, you'll select the `proj_no` and `dept_no`, with a `COUNT` aggregation on `emp_no`, and order your results by the the count of employees in descending order. Once you're content with the results, limit the return by adding a `TOP (1)` to your select so that you only return the answer to the question.

Comment: This makes a ton of sense. I will do my best to normalize my data and see if I can query it easier.